# Trying to convert a variant array to delimited string and always getting type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, office-2007

Ultimately I'm trying to write out a range into a text file. When I get the value of the range it returns a 2d variant array. However if I try to pass it to the converting function it gives me a type mismatch error.

The code is:

```
Dim Data As String
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("testfile.txt", True)
Data = ArrayToDelimitedString(wksMyWorkSheet.Range("rngMyRange").Value)
ts.Write (Data)
ts.Close

Public Function ArrayToDelimitedString(variantArray() As Variant) As String
   Dim delimitedString As String, index As Integer

   For index = 1 To UBound(variantArray(1))
      delimitedString = delimitedString & CStr(variantArray(1, index)) & ","
   Next
   ArrayToDelimitedString = Left(delimitedString, Len(delimitedString) - 1)
End Function
```

I'm wondering why the .Value returns a 2d array and why is it giving me this mismatch error.

Comment: wksMyWorkSheet.Range("rngMyRange").Value 
will return a 3D Array (A Variant containing Variant objects).

What type of Range are you using? A row? A column? an Area?

Comment: The range is a row. Is it a 3D array? When I step through the code, the locals shows that it is Variant/Variant(1 to 1, 1 to 7). Sorry, I've only been using VBA for a month so I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: Well, the Range method will always return a 3D Array. If you try to use the method Transpose with the 3D array, it'll transpose your matrix of elements (which is not what you needed). But for single rows or columns, it'll shift the datatype from Variant/Variant(1 to 1, 1 to 7) To Variant/String.

Comment: Is there any way to grab a range and put it into an array without using the Range method? So that it can be a 1D array with each array element representing a cell in the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Range() method returns a Variant of Variant.
In the case you want to use a 2D Array (Variant of Strings), use the Transpose method.

```
ArrayToDelimitedString(wApplication.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wksMyWorkSheet.Range("rngMyRange").Value))
```